# Generator with For In only returning first character instead of the whole string

Tags: python, loops, generator

I want this generator to return these characters in a loop: "><><><"
instead it's only returning the first character ">>>>>>"

if I replace yield with print it works correctly, why is it only returning the first character?

```
def gn():
    while True:
        for char in "><":
            yield char
print([next(gn()) for _ in range(10)])
```

I've tracked it to a problem in the For In part of the loop, but I still don't see what I'm doing wrong

```
def gn2():
    for char in [">","<"]:
        yield char
print([next(gn2()) for _ in range(10)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you call `gn()`, you create a new generator, which starts at the beginning of the sequence; calling `next()` on that freshly constructed generator always gives you the first item.  Call it once and keep a reference to it:

```
>>> g = gn()
>>> print([next(g) for _ in range(10)])
['>', '<', '>', '<', '>', '<', '>', '<', '>', '<']
```

Or construct a `for` loop where you're iterating over a single call to `gn()` instead of calling it inside the loop body:

```
>>> print([i for i, _ in zip(gn(), range(10))])
['>', '<', '>', '<', '>', '<', '>', '<', '>', '<']
```

Comment: That fixed it, ty!  I'll accept the answer once the 10 minute limit is up